# How to add dependency for @vaadin/vaadin-element-mixin in a gradle project

Tags: vaadin, vite, vaadin-flow

While trying to change and build the web-component SelectionGrid

```
import { ThemableMixin } from '@vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin';
import { ElementMixin } from '@vaadin/vaadin-element-mixin';
import { GridElement } from  '@vaadin/vaadin-grid/src/vaadin-grid.js';

import {
_getItemOverriden,
_selectionGridSelectRow,
_selectionGridSelectRowWithItem
} from './helpers';

class VcfSelectionGridElement extends ElementMixin(ThemableMixin(GridElement)) {

    constructor() {

....
```

i get a

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':vaadinBuildFrontend'.
> Vite process exited with non-zero exit code.
  Stderr: 'vite v3.2.5 building for production...
  transforming...
  ✓ 112 modules transformed.
  [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@vaadin/vaadin-element-mixin" from "frontend/src/vcf-sel-table.js".
  This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
  If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
  `build.rollupOptions.external`
  error during build:
  Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@vaadin/vaadin-element-mixin" from "frontend/src/vcf-sel-table.js".
  This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
  If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
  `build.rollupOptions.external`
      at onRollupWarning ()
      at onwarn ()
      at Object.onwarn ()
      at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId ()
      at
```

Obviously the dependency @vaadin/vaadin-element-mixin is missing. The dependency for the @vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin is present in the packages.json; but not the element-mixin. Since packages.json is generated by the vaadinPrepareFrontend task i do not have a clue where i can add that dependency.

I m also wondering where and how that @vaadin in typescript is resolved. I assume all the ts for the web-components is packaged in jar files ...

I tried to add a dependency to the gradle file - of course to no avail

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin:vaadin-element-mixin:2.4.2")
```

Any hint appreciated what i should investigate ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using Vaadin 23 and you have copied the code from the components repository's master branch, which is for Vaadin 14.

The correct import path is now:

```
import { ElementMixin } from '@vaadin/component-base/src/element-mixin';
```

Comment: Absolutely, cheers for your help on that ..